# how to get directory names under a path in Vim script?

Tags: function, vim, directory, path

I want a simple solution to get directory names under a path in vim script.

Here is my tried ways: the code. https://gist.github.com/4307744
Function is at line L84.

I use this function as complete function for input().
So this function need to return a list of directory names under a path.
e.g.

```
to/path/
        - a/
        - b/
```

I want to get `a` and `b`.

I tried to find vim internal functions with `:help functions`. only found `globpath()`, but it will return full path.

So does anyone have a simple solution ?
(BTW, why it is so hard to get directory names under a path in Vim ??)

Comment: What do you want to do with those names? You can always do a substitute to trim those full paths.

Comment: @romainl Don’t do `substitute()` for path manipulations, it is hard to get it right, simple and portable at the same time. There is `fnamemodify()` for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don’t know whether it was intentional, but `glob()` limits directories to only those with paths where the pattern ends with `/`:

```
let directories=glob(fnameescape(top_directory).'/{,.}*/', 1, 1)
call map(directories, 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":h:t")')
```

. Some explanations:

- `fnameescape()` escapes top_directory (it should be set to `to/path` in the example) in order to prevent special characters in it from being expanded on their own (I once used to have directory named `*.*`).
- `{,.}` is necessary because on unix vim won’t list files starting with dot by default. Note that normally `.*` pattern matches special `.` and `..` directories that are then removed, but due to some reason `{,.}*` does not match them.
- `, 1, 1` make `glob()` ignore `'suffixes'` and `'wildignore'` options (first) and return a list (second, requires most recent vim).
- Last (second) line is for keeping only directory names as you requested. Normally `:h:t` would return only parent directory name, but `glob()` outputs paths like `to/path/a/` and `:h` thus removes only the trailing slash. `:t` strips directory path (returns trailing path component). Without `:h` stripping slash trailing path component would be empty string.

You can join everything into one line:

```
let directories=map(glob(fnameescape(top_directory).'/{,.}*/', 1, 1), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":h:t")')
```