# Use the current directory in Vim commands

Tags: vim

For my Haskell programs, I know that the executable's name in the path is the same as my current directory's name. Now I want to create a mapping like so:

```
:map <leader>rr :!curdir()<cr>
```

However, the only command I know of is `getcwd()`, which gives me the whole path instead of just the directory's name.

Is there an easy way to extract only the directory's name?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13908273/546861).

Comment: The answers below are good vimscript solutions. If you don't have a map you can also evaluate this dynamically with = register. (after typing part of an ex command like `:!` type `C-R=` followed by one of the vimscript solutions below.

Comment: @darcyparker Neither is good. Don’t use any kind of regular expressions for such job as there is dedicated function for this. Anybody assuming `/` being a path separator is wrong. Anybody assuming `/` and `\ ` are *both* path separators is just as wrong. More, anybody assuming `\ ` is *always* path separator on windows is also wrong. I also have no idea under which circumstances path separator will be `:`, but it may be it. Most \*nix systems can have `\ ` and `:` in file names.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
fnamemodify(getcwd(), ':t')
```

or

```
fnamemodify('.', ':p:h:t')
```

. `:h` in the second case is necessary because `:p` emits trailing path separator (thus last path component selected by `:t` is now empty string).

To move this into your mapping use

```
:noremap \rr :!<C-r>=shellescape(fnamemodify('.', ':p:h:t'), 1)<CR><CR>
```

. For the description of why you should not ever use `:map` see [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
split(getcwd(), "/")[-1]
```

Comment: Path separator is not necessary `/`.

Comment: @ZyX, what operating system are you talking about?

Comment: Windows: here path separator is either `\` or `/` depending on `&shellslash` option. AFAIK Macintosh sometimes, here path separator may be `:`, but I do not know in which cases.

Comment: It should have been “`\ ` or `/`” in previous comment. Markdown parser here for some reason assumes that in backtick-backslash-backtick sequence backslash is escaping a backtick. Backtick-backslash-backslash-backtick does not work as well: backticks are displayed: `\\`.

Comment: MacOS before OSX used `:` as a directory separator if I understand correctly.